# Delete users from membership

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made a `GridView` with delete and edit link buttons to perform edit and delete action. This works for the edit button, but not for the delete button. What is the problem?

And when I run my application, it gives me this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@UserName"

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<Columns>
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsApproved" HeaderText="IsApproved"
SortExpression="IsApproved" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" 
SortExpression="UserName" />
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsLockedOut" HeaderText="IsLockedOut" 
SortExpression="IsLockedOut" />
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [IsApproved], [UserName], [IsLockedOut] FROM [vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers]" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers] SET IsApproved = @IsApproved, IsLockedOut = @IsLockedOut WHERE (UserName = @UserName)"
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers] WHERE (UserName = @UserName)">
<UpdateParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="IsApproved" />
<asp:Parameter Name="IsLockedOut" />
<asp:Parameter Name="UserName" />
</UpdateParameters> 
<DeleteParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="IsApproved" />
<asp:Parameter Name="IsLockedOut" />
<asp:Parameter Name="UserName" />
</DeleteParameters> 

</asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You should either delete via Membership ` Membership.DeleteUser(user.UserName)` or via Stored-Procedure `[dbo].[aspnet_Users_DeleteUser]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either delete via `Membership.DeleteUser(user.UserName)` or via Stored-Procedure `[dbo].[aspnet_Users_DeleteUser]`

http://www.salmontraining.com/SqlExpressZone/articles/deleting_users_from_membership.html

Comment: I would also use the stored proc. Change your delete statement to EXEC [dbo].[aspnet_Users_DeleteUser] and see if the parameter is picked up then.

Comment: @angusf: There are 4 parameters to provide (see link).

Comment: yes, sorry for the bad phasing, I should have added a (s). I didn't have a db in front of me at the time to name them but I was just referring to the parameter that was specifically mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to handle the "deleting" event of the SQLDataSource.  Call the asp.net membership api to do the delete from the code behind.

Make sure you import System.Web.Security, and then try something like this:

```
    // Delete Membership User 
    Membership.DeleteUser(UserName);
```

Deleting a record from a view isn't really the greatest approach anyhow.